# Does samba also have backdoor for ransomware attacks?

Tags: windows, samba, security

Recently windows systems got attacked by exploit the SMB, read some where that same situation now for samba in linux also. Is it true? then what we need to do?

Comment: "Read some where" ... please cite the link. For both case

Comment: @Anwar announced by us defence. more over visit [techtarget](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/news/2240148419/Dangerous-Samba-vulnerability-affects-all-Linux-systems)

Comment: [Another link](https://arstechnica.com/security/2017/05/a-wormable-code-execution-bug-has-lurked-in-samba-for-7-years-patch-now/)

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: You second link indicates two relatively simple fixes - adding a line to your smb.conf file, and ensuring that your routers do not expose port 445 to the internet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer, yes, and Samba have released an update

Samba has recently released an update for this

There have only been a few documented cases of this happening on a Linux system, and I have not seen any Linux Samba ransomware exploits

http://thehackernews.com/2017/05/samba-rce-exploit.html has some more information

There appeared to more than money motivating the Wannacry virus, it was also about establishing awareness, this isn't going to stop other people from picking up from this trend and using other services you may have enabled, this can be done through 0day attacks

The best way to protect yourself is to limit the service and features that you actually need and use, the only reason Windows users are most susceptible is due to the environment, the system is left open for convenience and ease of use, if you don't need Samba, then don't use it, if you want to use it, if you are going to run dozens of services on your PC I would suggest familiarising yourself with Linux security and the structure behind it